# My app is killed and getting push notification from firebase using FirebaseMessagingService. On push notification click i want to open the app

Tags: android

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

```
       Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Is your code not compiling? Is it crashing? Are you not able to have it open directly to your activity? Are you getting unexpected behavior? Or something else?

Comment: Nothing is happening and also not crashing.notification is coming but not going to the app

Comment: i got it now it has  worked